# Cant obtain md5 Fingerprint for api key

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to develop the map element of my app and I am having trouble obtaining a md5 fingerprint,  I am using Ubuntu and I have located the debug.keystore file, but when I enter the commands I get:

No command 'store' found, did you mean:
 Command '0store' from package 'zeroinstall-injector' (universe)
 Command 'stone' from package 'stone' (universe)
store: command not found

or;

Illegal option:  -key
Try keytool -help

I think the first error maybe incorrect file path but I think the second error is when I got it right.

Anyone Help with this

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is `keytool`, not `store`. Per the [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html), the command you need to run is:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

In your specific case, for Ubuntu, this turns into:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did copy the command from the developers website but I must have got the file path wrong as I say I linux but I haven't been using it very long